# Concatenation of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, concatenation, verilog, system-verilog

I have the following member in transaction:

```
bit [31:0] data [$];
```

The interface has the following input:

```
 logic [31:0] WDATA
```

In the driver, I want to assign the concatenation of the transaction data to itself.
For example if the data contains FFFFFFFF, I have to concatenate FFFFFFFF to FFFFFFFF, and then assign it to the virtual interface

pseudo code:

```
vif.DATA <= trx.data[i] (concatenation) trx.tata[i]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator `{}` (refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 11.4.12 Concatenation operators):

```
vif.DATA <= {trx.data[i], trx.tata[i]}
```